# Need FTP the file without storing interpreter file save in local through Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing

I am trying to do some image interpreter and trying to store them directly to FTP server.

But my steps like upload the image from local folder then it converts to mask image then it will have final output. But during my mask and final output scenarios, temporary images are getting save it local which I don't want.

But without storing the image in local I unable to save the file to FTP. Please help me with solution that output.save(mask_img_path) without this step how can store the image in FTP.

```
import errno
from flask import Flask,request
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import time
import random
import ftplib
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

input_img_path = "C:/Projects/Python/input/1.jpg"
output_img_path = "C:/Projects/Python/image-processing-2/image/output/"

mask_img_path = output_img_path + 'mask.png'
mask_img = 'mask.png'

input_img = Image.open(input_img_path)
output = remove(input_img)
output.save(mask_img_path) // without this step unable to FTP the file below because this step storing the mask images in the folder.

ftp = ftplib.FTP('host', 'username', 'password')

# Store the mask files into FTP
with open(mask_img_path, "rb") as file:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % mask_img, file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=2000)
```

Given about all my coding step and strying to FTP the converted image.

Comment: Can you provide a [example]? Because you have many variables that are not defined anywhere.

Comment: @EvensF, just updated the code to working sample. I this would work simply. But need to make it work to FTP without saving to local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) whenever you need to keep a file object in memory instead of having to save it to a temporary file. (But if you have big files that would not be practical to keep them all in memory, have a look at the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tempfile.html) module of the standard library.

Let's suppose that you have

- an FTP server

  - running on `localhost`
  - at port 60000
  - accessible with the user name "Manoj"
  - and password "Poosalingam"
- an image `1.jpg`
  [image: A dog on a wooden floor]

Using this code:

```py
import io
import ftplib
from PIL import Image
from rembg import remove

image_filename = "1.jpg"

with Image.open(image_filename) as input_image:
    with remove(input_image) as output:
        with io.BytesIO() as temporary_file:
            output.save(temporary_file, format='PNG')
            temporary_file.seek(0) # Rewinding to the start of the file

            with ftplib.FTP() as ftp_client:
                remote_filename = 'mask.png'
                ftp_client.connect(host='localhost', port=60000)
                ftp_client.login(user='Manoj', passwd='Poosalingam')
                ftp_client.storbinary(f'STOR {remote_filename}', temporary_file)
```

I get this `mask.png` image on the server:

[image: A dog with the background all stripped]

Is that what you needed?

Comment: Thanks Evens, I did this earlier. But your code also very much useful for few steps. Thats really superw. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I presume your question is really *"How do I call `ftplib.storbinary()` without needing a disk file. The short answer is via `io.BytesIO`:

Here we make a `PIL Image`

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Create dummy red PIL Image
output = Image.new('RGB', (320,240), 'red')
```

and save it in a`BytesIO`:

```
# Create in-memory JPEG
buffer = BytesIO()
output.save(buffer, format="JPEG")
```

Now you should be able to pass that to `ftplib()`:

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR image.jpg', buffer)
```

You may need to do the following before FTPing:

```
buffer.seek(0)
```

I can't test as I don't have any FTP servers.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Setchell, its useful. I tried this option but all the images are storing as 0KB file. I guess I am not sure how can incorporate output.save(mask_img)  with your code as thats my output image which is storing in Localhost (Which I need to store in FTP)

Comment: I've changed my variable names to be closer to your code.

Comment: Thanks, but still we are not giving the input image here. So its storing as 0KB. input_img = Image.open(input_img_path)
        output = remove(input_img)

Comment: What do you get with `print(type(output))` where `output` is result of `output = remove(...)` ?

Comment: Print output is <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>. And output.save(mask_img_path) saves the image file Local folder (I need to ignore this step and needs to store it FTP directly), thats my requirement. So basically output.save(mask_img_path) step creates the output file.

Comment: You need to do `output.save(buffer, format='JPEG')` then the JPEG will get stored in `buffer` and you pass that to FTP.

Comment: As you advised written code and getting error! input_img = Image.open('C:/Projects/Python/input/3.jpg')
        output = remove(input_img)
        output.save('mask.jpg')

        # Create in-memory JPEG
        buffer = BytesIO()
        output.save(buffer, format='JPEG')
        buffer.seek(0)

        ftp.storbinary('STOR image.jpg', buffer)


500 Error: <title>TypeError: The view function for 'result' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None
  or ended without a return statement.

Comment: That's a **Flask** error, but you don't seem to even have a view - or any function with `@route` decorator?

Comment: I have route. I just given locally working application above. But if I dont above code, its working fine no error. image basically not storing in buffer thats the issue.

Comment: It's hard to help debug code I can't see, or is incomplete, or only in comments where it is unformatted. Please click `edit` under your original question and add a new, latest/greatest simplest code at the end. And print the type and size of each variable just after it is created. Thank you.

Comment: Yes sure if this is not working I will debug further tomorrow and put more code. However found that issue when I use "output = remove(Image.open('C:/Projects/Python/input/2.jpg'))" its not working and I remove the keyword "remove" its working but without do the remove background function. So its loading to FTP if I don't use remove. But ideally I require this function.