# PIL Image Conversion

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Could you please advise how can we convert the <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=675x1200 at 0x16193333D48> to Real image through Python. Because when I storing outputimg in FTP its storing like "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=675x1200 at 0x16193333D48>" not actually the image.

When I do print
output --> C:/Projects/Python/input/2.jpg
outputimg --> <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=675x1200 at 0x16193333D48>

```
output = 'C:/Projects/Python/input/2.jpg'
outputimg = remove(Image.open(output))
print(output)
print(outputimg)
```

So appriciate someone help to convert this PIL value to real image.

Comment: What do you mean by "real image" ? Do you mean an openCV image ?

Comment: I think this question is the same as yours, isn't it (see link)? Here the image is loaded into a numpy array and you can look at the values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-do-i-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array

Comment: Have you tried [Image.save()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)? It saves an image as a file.

Comment: `Because when I storing outputimg in FTP its storing like` What code are you using to store the output image in FTP? If all you want to do is copy an image to FTP without changing it, I would suggest you avoid using PIL at all.

Comment: Hi Nick, I am actually removing the background of the image by doing remove(Image.open(output)) and storing that image directly to FTP, I don't want to save it in local. Image.save() save the file in local successfully. But my interest in saving the file directly in FTP. But FTP its storing like "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=675x1200 at 0x16193333D48>"

Comment: And can see full code where I am trying to upload converted image to FTP here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292103/need-ftp-the-file-without-storing-interpreter-file-save-in-local-through-python/74295390?noredirect=1#comment131168323_74295390