# Get a PIL.Image.save() image without reading it back from disk

Tags: python, image

```
from PIL import Image

fileDir = ""  #  original image path
comDir = ""  #  save path

imgFile = Image.open(fileDir)
imgFile.save(comDir, quality=quality)
```

I need to use the `quality` parameter of the `save()`, but I don't want to save the image in disk.

There is no return on `PIL.Image.save()`, I tried override the `save()`, but I couldn't.

Comment: Use `BytesIO` to store it in RAM instead of disk.

Comment: Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74295390/2836621